# Mask image with Jquery with height undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

How can i define special border (tops and bottom) for every image?. For example http://grab.by/csU6

If you check, the images has diagonals border on the top and bottom.

Thanks :)

Comment: (offtopic) You did not accepted any of the proposed answers. People will stop give you answers for your questions if don't upvote/accept answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.clip` function of canvas seems to fit the job just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/eGjak/333/.

```
ctx.moveTo(0, 100); // define path to draw in
ctx.lineTo(400, 0);
ctx.lineTo(400, 300);
ctx.lineTo(0, 400);
ctx.clip(); // constrain drawing to inside the path

var img = new Image;
img.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
};
img.src = "http://lorempixum.com/400/400/";​
```

Comment: @user1005729: Yes, that's correct. If you don't want to rely on the client you'd be best off doing it server-side instead...

Comment: @pimvdb Do you know others options?

Comment: @user1005729: Not really. Basically, if you're afraid the client doesn't support clipping then you shouldn't be doing it client-side.

Answer (score 0):

You can rotate/transform an image with CSS3, there are some jquery plugins for it as well

Comment: I don't have an example because is only an idea

Answer (score 0):

I think the image in the example is already processed like that. If you can't process the image on the server side another option is a transparent png overlay.

Comment: The image isn't processed, i used a mask with CSS, but don't work fine.

Comment: Oh, my bad, didn't realize it was a screen grab. Can you not just use a png overlay? Canvas is an option, but not very backwards compatible.

Comment: I use a PNG overlay but the height is undefined. I try canvas but only works on Modern Browsers :(

Comment: How can you mask an image with a fixed mask if you don't have a fixed height?

Comment: Put an absolute image with bottom 0 and ta-da! works fine but with small images is strange http://grab.by/csWo

Comment: It's going outside your mask. Set a fixed height and overflow:hidden.